# Migration away from Open Atrium

Tags: migrations

We have an intranet site running on Open Atrium (A product which has not been supported or updated in some time) and would like to migrate to a Vanilla Drupal install on either 8 or 9.

We do not use any custom code (we do use a few additional modules, which as far as I can tell are supported in at least 8.x).

Is there an accepted method for doing this?

I have tried disabling all the OA modules and then doing a migration but none of the content appears due to 'Content Types' being missing or wrong (this is my guess anyway) and there appear to be many OA fields in the database which other modules complain about.

Cheers

FooBar

Comment: You are likely looking at a scripted migration.

Comment: So, open atrium puts loads of fields in ie. field_oa_media I am guessing these need to be migrated to a different field type using the Node convert templates.

Comment: At that point its destination is up to you really - the conversion would happen in the migration definitions. But it is definitely possible to get out of OA and into your new structure in D9. It will just be a matter of devising Source plugins and destination configuration.

Comment: I have been reading this page - https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/writing-migrations-for-contributed-and-custom-modules and I must say it scares me! Surely this is something other people have done in the past considering OA is dead

Comment: I'm not sure how a generic migration would exist for this since most setups are probably unique in some way. I haven't used OA in a decade so I assume you will have to write your own migration path as Drupal does not understand the sources in OA unless it is told about it.